# How to customize Android call screen

Tags: android, phone-call

I want to customize my android ringing screen. When phone rings, it should show my application's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll have to look at the Intent Receivers, it should be something like: `ACTION_ANSWER`, defined for incoming calls.

Then you define your own application, an `Activity` with the design you want and properly configured to receive this kind of `Intent`.

Please refer to these links:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Comment: Thanks for the links, it would be really helpful . How can i put image in phone screen ? Another activity ?